# onchange not working for monthpicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Here is my  [code](http://jsfiddle.net/2YpsB/17/)
Unlike the datepicker the monthpicker doesn't open a web page when a month is selected.
What am i missing?

Comment: What do you mean? It seems to work for me

Comment: Seem to work on mine, did it NOT work on some specific browser?

Comment: I am using FF and chrome. when i select a month i don't have any reaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found the solution... with onClose.

**window.location.href= this.value;**
has to be in onClose for a web page to be open when a month is selected.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2YpsB/40/) is the full code.

Answer (score 1):

The monthpicker hijacks the onchange event and does not bubble it. You should do onChange via the library itself.

Comment: @mamesaye why didn't you use onChangeMonthYear?

Comment: @Christoffer Hallas: i am newbie, can elaborate plz

Comment: @mamesaye no... onChangeMonthYear goes into the original datepicker creation.

Comment: @dqhendricks:can u explain or update my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/2YpsB/26/) please.

Comment: @mamesaye dude, figure it out... http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onChangeMonthYear